# Safari - A MediaStreamTrack ended due to a capture failure

Tags: javascript, safari, webrtc, getusermedia

Today I upgraded to macOS Big Sur 11.0.1 and Safari 14, and my website (one-to-one video chat based on WebRTC) stopped working on Safari. After 10 seconds of a video call, the following console error appears: "A MediaStreamTrack ended due to a capture failure" and the other person can no longer see the video.

My code looks like this:

```
const userMedia = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true,
});

if (userMedia != null) {
    userMedia.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      otherRtcPeer.addTrack(track, userMedia);
    });
}
```

Is it a Safari bug or an implementation issue? And how to solve it?

Comment: It seems that other people are also experiencing this problem, looks like a Safari bug: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues/1281 - do you know any workaround?

Comment: yeah, having issues myself and it doesn't seem to fire "onended" for the track to at least be able to know. Apple is the new Internet Explorer...

Comment: I've also found that it's not possible to reproduce this issue in a local environment.

Comment: In our situation, we were detaching and reataching video elements into DOM, and somehow that was causing issues. I have no idea why. Now we use an always-there video element and re-attach to it ad nauseam as needed.

Comment: any update on this issue, i am also experiencing same issue. We have react component using html5 video element to capture images. All of a sudden in middle of the flow after capturing some pictures, its getting into the same error. I am trying to understand whether our implementation has to get chance with iOS/safari update

Comment: Issue mentioned above from me has been resolved. I made changes to clone the stream object before assigning to video element srcObject and have the MediaStream track stopped end of capture of each picture in the flow. The stream object is saved in react state and reused on re-render of video element

Answer (score 0):

After going through this [guide](https://webrtchacks.com/guide-to-safari-webrtc/), I have made changes and resolved the issue.

1. Have stream object in react state
2. when video element render/re-render the stream object is cloned and assigned to video element srcObject
3. After capture of the picture, stop all media tracks in the stream.

This way error mentioned above has been overcome.

Answer (score -2):

I was able to fix the issue on my end by styling a video element I'm using as a webGL texture as display:block, opacity:0 (instead of display: none).

Perhaps they removed the ability to play offscreen video textures on ios14/big sur.

Comment: It's not related to this bug.